# python: numpy: concatenation of named arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the following simple example:

```
x = numpy.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype=[('a','<f4'),('b','<f4')])
y = numpy.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype=[('c','<f4'),('d','<f4')])
numpy.hstack((x,y))
```

One will get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 226, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(list(map(atleast_2d,tup)),0)
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

If array had not titles it works

```
x = numpy.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype='<f4')
y = numpy.array([(1,2),(3,4)],dtype='<f4')
numpy.hstack((x,y))
```

If I remove the names from x and y it works too.

Question: how to concatenate, vstack or hstack of titled numpy array ?
Note: numpy.lib.recfunctions.stack_arrays doesn't work well either

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the types are different. The "title" is part of the type, and `y` uses different names from `x`, so the types are incompatible. If you use compatible types, everything works fine:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4')])
>>> y = numpy.array([(5, 6), (7, 8)], dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4')])
>>> numpy.vstack((x, y))
array([[(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0)],
       [(5.0, 6.0), (7.0, 8.0)]], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4')])
>>> numpy.hstack((x, y))
array([(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 6.0), (7.0, 8.0)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4')])
>>> numpy.dstack((x, y))
array([[[(1.0, 2.0), (5.0, 6.0)],
        [(3.0, 4.0), (7.0, 8.0)]]], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4')])
```

Sometimes `dstack`, etc. are smart enough to coerce types in a sensible way, but `numpy` has no way to know how to combine record arrays with different user-defined field names.

If you want to concatenate the *datatypes*, then you have to create a new datatype. Don't make the mistake of thinking that the sequence of names (`x['a']`, `x['b']`...) constitutes a true dimension of the array; `x` and `y` above are *1-d arrays* of blocks of memory, each of which contains two 32-bit floats that can be accessed using the names `'a'` and `'b'`. But as you can see, if you access an individual item in the array, you don't get another array as you would if it were truly a second dimension. You can see the difference here:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4')])
>>> x[0]
(1.0, 2.0)
>>> type(x[0])
<type 'numpy.void'>

>>> z = numpy.array([(1, 2), (3, 4)])
>>> z[0]
array([1, 2])
>>> type(z[0])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

This is what allows record arrays to contain heterogenous data; record arrays can contain both strings and ints, but the trade-off is that you don't get the full power of an `ndarray` at the level of individual records.

The upshot is that to join individual blocks of memory, you actually have to modify the `dtype` of the array. There are a few ways to do this but the simplest I could find involves the little-known `numpy.lib.recfunctions` library (which I see you've already found!):

```
>>> numpy.lib.recfunctions.rec_append_fields(x, 
                                             y.dtype.names, 
                                             [y[n] for n in y.dtype.names])
rec.array([(1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f4'), ('d', '<f4')])
```

Comment: But this is not what I am looking for... I want the new array to have titles inherited from the join... e.g. after hstack I want to have titles: 'a','b','c','d'. Why does python care about the names and not just for the type?! Drives me nuts. I think I need to use Pandas rather than directly numpy.

Comment: @HananShteingart, you're using the wrong approach then -- you have to create a brand new datatype. It seems like you're wrongly assuming that `x` and `y` are 2-d arrays. They're not. See my edits above.